# Flatlist Horizontal without sticky header in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I am using flatlist to render some items collected from firestore and I have a problem with ListHeaderComponent prop.
The header is placed to the left and I need to place it on the top of the 1st item (see 2nd image below) and when moved it has to be fixed with the first item of the list as the image.

**Currently**

[Horizontal flatlist with ListHeaderComponent on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLjBA.jpg)

**I need to achieve this when scrolling left:**

[Horizontal flatlist with ListHeaderComponent on the top of 1st item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dN9V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate header text from `FlatList`. Use `Text` apparently to show the header.

**EDIT**

If you want to scroll text with a list you can use `FlatList` inside `ScrollView`. In this case, you may disable scrolling for `FlatList`. Please check below for detail.

```html
<ScrollView horizontal>
    <Text>Header Text</Text>
    <FlatList scrollEnabled={false} />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But `Text` should be scrolled at the same time with `FlatList`, is it possible?

Comment: In that case, you can use `ScrollView`. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved! Here's the code:

```
 <ScrollView horizontal={true}
   <View>
      <Text>Header Text</Text>
      <FlatList horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled={false} />
      </FlatList>
   </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

Thank you @baymax :)